# Audio Devices Disappeared After Trying to Fix Bluetooth Problems

Tags: linux, audio, debian, bluetooth

I couldn't connect my Sony earphones via Bluetooth.

This is the error I encountered with blutoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

and this is the error in logs:

`debian bluetoothd[3748]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: Protocol not available`

After trying to fix it with no success, I followed [these instuctions](https://gist.github.com/freyes/dfc3f5232526a62bbc09adc816e0477d):

> 1. In /etc/pulse/default.pa, comment out: #load-module module-bluetooth-discover

> 2. In /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11, add the following line: /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

When I restarted, the internet wasn't available and there were no audio devices in the Audio Volume menu in KDE.
I then edited the files to their original state and restarted. Internet came back but there are still no audio devices.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try the solutions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172000/a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed).

Comment: @harrymc didn't work for me